# How do you use Wild Cards in Assert.Equal C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to compare a string but the document no in my string is always different and I don't want my unit test to fail. I really just want to check if the document posted.

In my example, it is the document no that may not match.

```
Assert.AreEqual("1 Document(s) Posted. Document QA00752 has been created.", 
    message, "Post Confirmation Message does not match expected");
```

Any suggestions? I could find out what the document no is supposed to be by checking the data in the database and write it out to a variable but I don't know how to put it in my statement above.

```
string doc = "some code goes here"
```

Perhaps

```
Assert.AreEqual("1 Document(s) Posted. Document " + doc + " has been created.", 
    message, "Post Confirmation Message does not match expected");
```

Comment: You're looking for a regex.

Comment: if the document number is always different, then a good possibility is your test is not good.  Unit tests shouldn't have things that vary run to run

Comment: Actually, my variable didn't work because the document gets created after the message is displayed so it is always off by 1 number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that trying to parse a message to remove specific identifiers is problematic. If this is just a one-time thing, and you won't be checking various strings as a habit in your testing, then a simple `.Contains` or a regex could work.

But, if you're doing this task all over the place, then perhaps some abstraction is in order. Have you considered making your log messages into an object instead of a simple string?

```
public sealed class Notification {
   public string Message { get; set; }
   public string Identifier { get; set; }
   public int? Count { get; set; }
}
```

Then when you're working with these notifications such as in a unit test, you can compare the `Message` property to see it's identical, but ignore the `Identifier` and `Count`.

Here's another way you could do it:

```
public sealed class InterpolatedString {
   public InterpolatedString(string stringWithPlaceholders, params string[] values) {
      StringWithPlaceholders = stringWithPlaceholders;
      Values = values;
   }

   public string StringWithPlaceholders { get; }
   public string[] Values { get; }
   public override string ToString() => string.Format(StringWithPlaceholders, Values);
}
```

You'd create that like this:

```
return new InterpolatedString(
   "{0} Document(s) Posted. Document {1} has been created.",
   $"{count:#,##0}",
   documentCode
);
```

Then when testing or grouping, you have access to the non-interpolated string.

```
var actual = DoTest();
Assert.AreEqual(
   "{0} Document(s) Posted. Document {1} has been created.",
   actual.StringWithPlaceholders
);
```

And finally, any time you want the actual string, you can just do `ToString()` or let it get implicitly run when a compiler-supported implicit conversion to string occurs.

There is the problem of having to repeat a string and the risk of breaking a unit test if you change the string in the code. However, if you put your strings into a resource file, then you don't even need to repeat them in two places—you can just use the resource file to spit them out. Another option is to keep strings in public static members instead of embedded deep in the code.

Comment: @KevinRaffay If this is the only place in the whole system that it's being used, then yes. But I think it very likely that if the asker's unit testing pattern is to check for these sorts of messages, he'll be using them all over the place. You're jumping to conclusions. An object like this is NOT overbuilding.

Answer (score 1):

If you need pattern matching, then a regular expression (as mentioned by SLaks) is the cleanest way to go:

```
Assert.IsTrue(
    Regex.IsMatch(message, @"1 Document\(s\) Posted. Document QA\d+ has been created."),
    "Post Confirmation Message does not match expected");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just assert that the message Contains("has been created"), unless there are conditions where that won't pass.

Comment: Assert.IsTrue(message.Contains("has been created.");